# Send mail to multiple multiple recipients using outlook interop

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to use a script to send to multiple users, but this will not work. it currently works with one mail address, I have tried to use ; , . as separator without any help.

do anyone have an idea?

oRecipient = oMail.Recipients.Add([To])
oRecipient.Resolve()

Comment: If the outlook-vba tag is correct then search with [outlook*] [*vba] multiple recipients

Answer (score 1):

Call `Recipients.Add` for **each** recipient. Or set the `To` / `CC` / `BCC` properties to a `";"` separated list of names or addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/recipients-add-method-outlook) method of the `Recipients` class creates a new recipient in the `Recipients` collection. The method accepts the name of the recipient; it can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP e-mail address of the recipient. For example:

```
Sub CreateStatusReportToBoss() 
  Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
  Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 

  Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
  Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev") 
  myItem.Subject = "Status Report" 
  myItem.Display 
End Sub
```

Also you can use the `To`, `Cc` and `Bcc` properties of the MailItem class.

You can read more about that in the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article.